# Error while reading ConnectionString from App.config file

Tags: c#, connection-string, app-config, configuration-files

I have this App.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ACWConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=ASHISH-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=ACW;User ID=ash159;Password=password"/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

which I am using here:

```
string connstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ACWConnectionString"].ToString();
```

Here I am getting an error 'NullReferenceException was unhandled'..
Why I am getting this error?
ThankYou!!
Tried these too but getting the same error:

```
 string connstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ACWConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
 string connstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ACWConnectionString"].ConnectionString.ToString();
```

Note: I have added System.configuration and also set the reference to it.
I would also like you to know that I have 3 projects(Admin,Employee,Database) in a single project(ABC). i have added reference of Database to Admin and Employee. And then made the Database class in those two projects wherever needed to get connection.
Database class is as follows:

```
 public class database
     {
            SqlConnection connection;
            string connstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ACWConnectionString"].ToString();
            public SqlConnection connect()
            {
                connection=new SqlConnection(connstring);
                return connection;
            }
        }
```

It is in Database project that I have added the App.config file.

Comment: Working for me. Are you sure you are getting null reference on this line only?

Comment: I tried the same thing you trying and it's working. Are you sure the connstring can access the App.Config file

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:-

```
string connstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ACWConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
```

Comment: Check app.config ...it has to be in the running project?

Comment: It must be in the Database project right? As I am passing the connection string from Database to other projects.

Comment: It must be in the project that is the executable, not the database project.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way of reading connection string is to read it via ConnectionString property.

```
 string connstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ACWConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
```

by the way i have tried and this works just as well

```
string connstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ACWConnectionString"].ToString();
```

which means that the code isn't a problem. `Add your app.config in the exe project.` If you add app.config in the main(exe) project you can access it in database as well, as app.config of your executable is added to the bin (unless any other is added explicitly).

Comment: @ash i think your problem isn't this code. You don't have app.config in the project and this is the read errod

Comment: @EhsanUllah - Instead of posting same answer you could have upvote other answer. Posting exactly same answer doesn't add any value to this post.

Comment: @RohitVats i have posted that code isn't a problem. You can't downvote correct answer.

Comment: @ash check the updated answer. Add your app.config in the exe project.

Comment: @Ehsan Ullah My projects Admin and Employee are both exe but I am passing the connection string to them from Database by referencing to to both of them. So the App.config shouldn't be in Database? But I must try what you told.

Comment: @ash if Admin and Employee are 2 separate executable than it should be in both of them. Open the bin folder and you will see that app.config of database project won't be present there. After you add to your executables it will be there.

Comment: Thank You it worked.. :) The error went away.. Although i am not getting any error now but no data is read from the database.. :(

Comment: well that is a separate question now. Post it with the code in a separate question and i will take a look. You can accept this one though,

Comment: @EhsanUllah I checked the bin folder of both the executables projects and didn't find the config file. I have already released my project. Might this be the reason that now the configuration file is not getting added to bin?

Comment: @ash in debug mode you will find it in bin whereas in release mode you will find it in release folder.

Comment: I found it out.. Thank you v.v.much.. :)

Comment: @RohitVats would you mind removing your negative vote on a accepted answer?

Answer (score 0):

Add a reference to `System.Configuration.dll`, then you should be able to use the `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager`.